# Wireless system (transmitter and receiver) for XLR lavalier microphones and audio recorder?

Tags: microphone, recording, wireless, lavalier, xlr

Please forgive me, if this question sounds rather basic or even noobish to some of you. I've been trying to do some research into the technology, but, so far, have not been able to find answers to very specific questions that I'm facing.

Here's the situation: I currently own a great condenser microphone (*Rode NT2-A*), two lavalier microphones that I would deem okay and a portable audio recorder that I'm very happy with (*Tascam DR-40*). The whole system is based on XLR connections.

So far, I have only worked with long XLR cables, connecting two microphones to the recorder, when doing interviews. Now, for an upcoming event there will arise the need to have a photographer walking freely throughout the studio during a fashion shoot, while he's being interviewed. For budget reasons I would like to make use of my existing system, if possible, but would like to find a way to achieve a **wireless connection** somehow...

- In researching different options I came across a few complete "systems", including a microphone, a cable-connected transmitter, a big and professional-looking receiver, a separate recorder and whatnot. Are such complete systems considered advantageous in any way, compared to simply extending my existing setup?
- I also came across transmitters that are using XLR connections, while the corresponding receivers use jack plugs. Needless to say, these don't seem to make sense in my setup, but... is there any advantage to that?
- I found a few systems consisting of a combination of small and simple transmitters and receivers that seem to be be perfectly suited to what I need (by Nux, Xvive and Sennheiser), but also read some mixed reviews regarding quality, especially, when the line of sight is even slightly blocked. That sounds, as if it's of no use for me, or is it?
- Will it make a difference, if the microphone is phantom powered (like my NT2-A) or not?

So, to make a long story short: Can anybody help me understand, what it is that I need and what criteria I will need to look out for? Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of options here. The most practical will be a wireless lavalier kit. Typical devices are the Rode Wireless Go or the Sennheiser G3. Some manufacturers also offer a 'butt-plug' style device which allows you to attach a transmitter directly to a handheld microphone directly via the XLR connection. However, handheld use of the mic is required. Best to go with a lavalier style mic unless you want to use handheld.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I think the "butt-plug" style is, what I was referring to in point 3 above. With such systems -- but also when using lavalier microphones: Will there be any issue, when the transmitter is hidden away? I read a few review that mentioned that these gadgets need an unblocked line of sight...

Comment: Also, it seems, the systems that you mentioned don't use XLR, do they?

Comment: Line-of-sight requirements are dependent on a number of things. 1) frequency band (lower frequencies are less reliant on LOS) 2) modulation strategy 3) frequency agility. For instance high-frequency (2GHz) devices are generally better with good line of sight, but this can be mitigated with clever modulation strategies and frequency agility / diversity.